# "python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully" Installing pandana

Tags: python, installation, package, python-packaging, python-install

The problem:

```
Building wheels for collected packages: pandana, tables
  Building wheel for pandana (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [47 lines of output]
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\pandana
      copying pandana\network.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\pandana
      copying pandana\testing.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\pandana
      copying pandana\utils.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\pandana
      copying pandana\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\pandana
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\pandana\loaders
      copying pandana\loaders\osm.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\pandana\loaders
      copying pandana\loaders\pandash5.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\pandana\loaders
      copying pandana\loaders\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\pandana\loaders
      running build_ext
      skipping 'src\cyaccess.cpp' Cython extension (up-to-date)
      building 'pandana.cyaccess' extension
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-311
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-311\Release
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-311\Release\src
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-311\Release\src\contraction_hierarchies
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-311\Release\src\contraction_hierarchies\src
      "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.34.31933\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe" /c /nologo /O2 /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -I. "-IC:\Users\Diego DM\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\include" "-IC:\Users\Diego DM\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Include" "-IC:\Users\Diego DM\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.34.31933\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.34.31933\ATLMFC\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Auxiliary\VS\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22000.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22000.0\\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22000.0\\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22000.0\\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22000.0\\cppwinrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.8\include\um" /EHsc /Tpsrc/accessibility.cpp /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-cpython-311\Release\src/accessibility.obj /w /openmp
      cl : L¡nea de comandos warning D9025 : invalidando '/W3' con '/w'
      accessibility.cpp
      C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.34.31933\include\utility(200): warning C4244: 'inicializando': conversi¢n de '_Ty' a '_Ty2'; posible p‚rdida de datos
              with
              [
                  _Ty=float
              ]
              and
              [
                  _Ty2=int
              ]
      src/accessibility.cpp(193): note: Vea la referencia a la creaci¢n de una instancia de la funci¢n plantilla "std::pair<double,int>::pair<double,float,0>(std::pair<double,float> &&) noexcept" que se est  compilando
      src/accessibility.cpp(192): note: Vea la referencia a la creaci¢n de una instancia de la funci¢n plantilla "std::pair<double,int>::pair<double,float,0>(std::pair<double,float> &&) noexcept" que se est  compilando
      "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.34.31933\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe" /c /nologo /O2 /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -I. "-IC:\Users\Diego DM\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\include" "-IC:\Users\Diego DM\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Include" "-IC:\Users\Diego DM\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.34.31933\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.34.31933\ATLMFC\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Auxiliary\VS\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22000.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22000.0\\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22000.0\\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22000.0\\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22000.0\\cppwinrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.8\include\um" /EHsc /Tpsrc/contraction_hierarchies/src/libch.cpp /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-cpython-311\Release\src/contraction_hierarchies/src/libch.obj /w /openmp
      cl : L¡nea de comandos warning D9025 : invalidando '/W3' con '/w'
      libch.cpp
      "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.34.31933\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe" /c /nologo /O2 /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -I. "-IC:\Users\Diego DM\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\include" "-IC:\Users\Diego DM\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Include" "-IC:\Users\Diego DM\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.34.31933\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.34.31933\ATLMFC\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Auxiliary\VS\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22000.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22000.0\\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22000.0\\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22000.0\\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22000.0\\cppwinrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.8\include\um" /EHsc /Tpsrc/graphalg.cpp /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-cpython-311\Release\src/graphalg.obj /w /openmp
      cl : L¡nea de comandos warning D9025 : invalidando '/W3' con '/w'
      graphalg.cpp
      "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.34.31933\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe" /c /nologo /O2 /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -I. "-IC:\Users\Diego DM\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\include" "-IC:\Users\Diego DM\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Include" "-IC:\Users\Diego DM\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.34.31933\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.34.31933\ATLMFC\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Auxiliary\VS\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22000.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22000.0\\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22000.0\\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22000.0\\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22000.0\\cppwinrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.8\include\um" /EHsc /Tpsrc\cyaccess.cpp /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-cpython-311\Release\src\cyaccess.obj /w /openmp
      cl : L¡nea de comandos warning D9025 : invalidando '/W3' con '/w'
      cyaccess.cpp
      src\cyaccess.cpp(196): fatal error C1083: No se puede abrir el archivo incluir: 'longintrepr.h': No such file or directory
      error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2022\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.34.31933\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit code 2
      [end of output]
```

What I have already tried:

- pip install pandana
- pip install --upgrade pip setuptools wheel

My system:

- Windows 11, 64 Bit
- Python 3.11.1
- Microsoft Visual Studio Build Tools 2022 (17.4.3)

I would like to find the way to install "pandana".